# Resolve parent child hierarchy in Power Query M code with sorting columns

Tags: excel, dax, m-code

Based on [this article](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2019/10/03/parent-child-hierarchies-with-multiple-parents-in-power-bi-with-power-query/)

And this question posted on the [power bi forums](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Add-index-to-hierarchy-leves-for-later-sorting/m-p/851839)

### Objectives:

Resolve a hierarchy (parent - child relationship) in *Power Query* adding levels and their corresponding sorting columns.

The final result can be used in a Power Pivot table and use it to generate a dynamic P&L.

Key point was to add the sorting levels, so you can in *Power Pivot* use the `Sort by column` feature

One can achieve this with *DAX* formulas.

---

[image: Source table]

---

[image: Results]

---

### **Code**

```
let func =  

(SourceTable as table,
NodeKey as text,
ParentKey as text,
LabelColumn as text,
Prefix as text,
CompleteOutput as logical) =>

let

/*
    //Debug Parameters
    //Debug Parameters
    SourceTable = TableSample,
    NodeKey = "Account",
    ParentKey = "AccountParent",
    LabelColumn = "Name",
    CompleteOutput = true,
    Prefix = "C",
*/




    SelectRelevantColumns = Table.SelectColumns(SourceTable, {NodeKey,ParentKey,LabelColumn}),

    ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SelectRelevantColumns, {
        {NodeKey,type text},
        {ParentKey,type text}
    }),

    ReplaceNulls = Table.ReplaceValue(ChangeType, null, "", Replacer.ReplaceValue, {ParentKey}),

    MissingParents = List.Buffer(List.Select(List.Difference(List.Distinct(Table.Column(ReplaceNulls, ParentKey)), List.Distinct(Table.Column(ReplaceNulls, NodeKey))), each _ <> "")),

    AddMissingParents = Table.Buffer(Table.Combine({
        ReplaceNulls,
        #table({
            NodeKey,
            LabelColumn,
            ParentKey
        }, List.Transform(MissingParents, each {
            _,
            "Unknown TopLevel" & Text.From(List.PositionOf(MissingParents, _)),
            ""
        }))
    })),

    MergeQueriesMissingParents = Table.NestedJoin(AddMissingParents, {NodeKey}, AddMissingParents, {ParentKey}, "SelectRelevantColumns", JoinKind.LeftOuter),

    CheckIfIsLeaf = Table.AddColumn(MergeQueriesMissingParents, "IsLeaf", each
        if Table.IsEmpty([SelectRelevantColumns]) then "yes"
        else "no", type logical),

    ReplaceNullsParentLabelCols = Table.ReplaceValue(CheckIfIsLeaf, null, "", Replacer.ReplaceValue, {
        ParentKey,
        LabelColumn
    }),

    AddStartPath = Table.AddColumn(ReplaceNullsParentLabelCols, "Path", each Text.Trim(Record.Field(_, NodeKey) & "|" & Record.Field(_, ParentKey), "|")),

    AddTempLabelColumn = Table.DuplicateColumn(AddStartPath, LabelColumn, "TempLabelColumn"),

    AddTempParentKeyColumn = Table.DuplicateColumn(AddTempLabelColumn, ParentKey, "TempParentKey"),

    // Retrieve all parents per row
    fnRetrieveAllParents = List.Generate(() => [Result = AddTempParentKeyColumn, Level = 1],
        each Table.RowCount([Result]) > 0 and[Level] <= 7,
        each [Result =
            let
                MergeQueries = Table.NestedJoin([Result], {
                    ParentKey
                }, AddMissingParents, {
                    NodeKey
                }, "Added Custom", JoinKind.Inner),
                RemoveColumns1 = Table.RemoveColumns(MergeQueries, {
                    ParentKey
                }),
                ExpandAddedCustom = Table.ExpandTableColumn(RemoveColumns1, "Added Custom", {
                    ParentKey,
                    LabelColumn
                }, {
                    "ParentKey.1",
                    "Name.1"
                }),
                DuplicateColumn = Table.DuplicateColumn(ExpandAddedCustom, "ParentKey.1", ParentKey),
                MergeColumns = Table.CombineColumns(DuplicateColumn, {
                    "Path",
                    "ParentKey.1"
                }, Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None), "Path"),
                MergeColumns2 = Table.CombineColumns(MergeColumns, {
                    LabelColumn,
                    "Name.1"
                }, Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None), LabelColumn) in
                MergeColumns2,
                Level = [Level] + 1
        ]),

    ConvertAllParentsToTable = Table.FromList(fnRetrieveAllParents, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),

    ExpandAllParentsLevel = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(ConvertAllParentsToTable, "Column1", {"Result","Level"}, {"Result","Level"}),

    ExpandAllParentsResult = Table.ExpandTableColumn(ExpandAllParentsLevel, "Result", {LabelColumn,ParentKey,NodeKey,"Path","TempLabelColumn","TempParentKey"}, {"LabelColumn","ParentKey","NodeKey","Path","TempLabelColumn","TempParentKey"}),

    FilterAllParents = Table.SelectRows(ExpandAllParentsResult, each([ParentKey] = null or [ParentKey] = "")),
    RemoveParentKeyCol = Table.RemoveColumns(FilterAllParents, {
        "ParentKey"
    }),
    RemoveLastPipeFromPath = Table.TransformColumns(RemoveParentKeyCol, {
        {
            "Path",
            each Text.Trim(_, "|")
        }
    }),
    ReverseOrderLabelColumn = Table.TransformColumns(RemoveLastPipeFromPath, {
        {
            "LabelColumn",
            each Text.Combine(List.Reverse(Text.Split(_, "|")), "|")
        }
    }),
    ReverseOrderPath = Table.TransformColumns(ReverseOrderLabelColumn, {
        {
            "Path",
            each Text.Combine(List.Reverse(Text.Split(_, "|")), "|")
        }
    }),
    ReorderTempCols = Table.ReorderColumns(ReverseOrderPath, {
        "NodeKey",
        "TempParentKey",
        "Path",
        "TempLabelColumn",
        "Level",
        "LabelColumn"
    }),
    SplitLabelColByLevel = Table.SplitColumn(ReorderTempCols, "LabelColumn", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), List.Transform({
        1..Table.RowCount(ConvertAllParentsToTable)
    }, each Prefix & " Level " & Text.From(_))),

    // Fill to the right
    DemoteHeaders = Table.DemoteHeaders(SplitLabelColByLevel),

    TransposeTable = Table.Transpose(DemoteHeaders),

    FillDown = Table.FillDown(TransposeTable, Table.ColumnNames(TransposeTable)),

    DeTransposeTable = Table.Transpose(FillDown),

    PromoteHeaders = Table.PromoteHeaders(DeTransposeTable, [PromoteAllScalars = true]),

    MergeSourceTable = Table.NestedJoin(PromoteHeaders, {
        "NodeKey",
        "TempParentKey"
    }, Table.ReplaceValue(SourceTable, null, "", Replacer.ReplaceValue, {ParentKey}), {
        NodeKey,
        ParentKey
    }, "MergedSourceTable", JoinKind.LeftOuter),

    ExpandSourceTable = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeSourceTable, "MergedSourceTable", List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(SourceTable), Table.ColumnNames(ReplaceNullsParentLabelCols))),

    ListParents = List.Buffer(ExpandSourceTable[TempParentKey]),

    AddColIsLeaf = Table.AddColumn(ExpandSourceTable, "IsLeaf", each not List.Contains(ListParents, [NodeKey])),

    RenameTempCols = Table.RenameColumns(AddColIsLeaf, {
        {
            "Level",
            "HierarchyDepth"
        },
        {
            "NodeKey",
            NodeKey
        },
        {
            "TempLabelColumn",
            LabelColumn
        },
        {
            "TempParentKey",
            ParentKey
        }
    }),

    AddLevelSorting = Table.AddColumn(RenameTempCols, Prefix & " Sorting", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(Text.Split([Path], "|"), each Text.AfterDelimiter(_, ".", {
        0,
        RelativePosition.FromEnd
    })), "|")),

    ExpandLevelSorting = Table.SplitColumn(AddLevelSorting, Prefix & " Sorting", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), List.Transform({
        1..Table.RowCount(ConvertAllParentsToTable)
    }, each Prefix & " Sorting " & Text.From(_))),

    AddColumnLevel2 =
    if Table.HasColumns(ExpandLevelSorting, Prefix & " Level 2") then ExpandLevelSorting
else Table.AddColumn(ExpandLevelSorting, Prefix & " Level 2", each null, type text),

    AddColumnLevel3 =
    if Table.HasColumns(AddColumnLevel2, Prefix & " Level 3") then AddColumnLevel2
else Table.AddColumn(AddColumnLevel2, Prefix & " Level 3", each null, type text),

    AddColumnLevel4 =
    if Table.HasColumns(AddColumnLevel3, Prefix & " Level 4") then AddColumnLevel3
else Table.AddColumn(AddColumnLevel3, Prefix & " Level 4", each null, type text),

    AddColumnLevel5 =
    if Table.HasColumns(AddColumnLevel4, Prefix & " Level 5") then AddColumnLevel4
else Table.AddColumn(AddColumnLevel4, Prefix & " Level 5", each null, type text),

    AddColumnLevel6 =
    if Table.HasColumns(AddColumnLevel5, Prefix & " Level 6") then AddColumnLevel5
else Table.AddColumn(AddColumnLevel5, Prefix & " Level 6", each null, type text),

    AddColumnLevel7 =
    if Table.HasColumns(AddColumnLevel6, Prefix & " Level 7") then AddColumnLevel6
else Table.AddColumn(AddColumnLevel6, Prefix & " Level 7", each null, type text),

    AddColumnSorting2 =
    if Table.HasColumns(AddColumnLevel7, Prefix & " Sorting 2") then AddColumnLevel7
else Table.AddColumn(AddColumnLevel7, Prefix & " Sorting 2", each null, Int64.Type),

    AddColumnSorting3 =
    if Table.HasColumns(AddColumnSorting2, Prefix & " Sorting 3") then AddColumnSorting2
else Table.AddColumn(AddColumnSorting2, Prefix & " Sorting 3", each null, Int64.Type),

    AddColumnSorting4 =
    if Table.HasColumns(AddColumnSorting3, Prefix & " Sorting 4") then AddColumnSorting3
else Table.AddColumn(AddColumnSorting3, Prefix & " Sorting 4", each null, Int64.Type),

    AddColumnSorting5 =
    if Table.HasColumns(AddColumnSorting4, Prefix & " Sorting 5") then AddColumnSorting4
else Table.AddColumn(AddColumnSorting4, Prefix & " Sorting 5", each null, Int64.Type),

    AddColumnSorting6 =
    if Table.HasColumns(AddColumnSorting5, Prefix & " Sorting 6") then AddColumnSorting5
else Table.AddColumn(AddColumnSorting5, Prefix & " Sorting 6", each null, Int64.Type),

    AddColumnSorting7 =
    if Table.HasColumns(AddColumnSorting6, Prefix & " Sorting 7") then AddColumnSorting6
else Table.AddColumn(AddColumnSorting6, Prefix & " Sorting 7", each null, Int64.Type),

    ReorderCols = Table.ReorderColumns(AddColumnSorting7, Table.ColumnNames(SourceTable) & {
        "Path",
        "HierarchyDepth",
        "IsLeaf",
        Prefix & " Level 1",
        Prefix & " Level 2",
        Prefix & " Level 3",
        Prefix & " Level 4",
        Prefix & " Level 5",
        Prefix & " Level 6",
        Prefix & " Level 7",
        Prefix & " Sorting 1",
        Prefix & " Sorting 2",
        Prefix & " Sorting 3",
        Prefix & " Sorting 4",
        Prefix & " Sorting 5",
        Prefix & " Sorting 6",
        Prefix & " Sorting 7"}),

    ChangeColTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(ReorderCols, {
        {
            NodeKey,
            type text
        },
        {
            LabelColumn,
            type text
        },
        {
            ParentKey,
            type text
        },
        {
            "Path",
            type text
        },
        {
            "HierarchyDepth",
            Int64.Type
        },
        {
            "IsLeaf",
            type logical
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Level 1",
            type text
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Level 2",
            type text
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Level 3",
            type text
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Level 4",
            type text
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Level 5",
            type text
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Level 6",
            type text
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Level 7",
            type text
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 1",
            Int64.Type
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 2",
            Int64.Type
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 3",
            Int64.Type
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 4",
            Int64.Type
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 5",
            Int64.Type
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 6",
            Int64.Type
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 7",
            Int64.Type
        }
    }), SortCols = Table.Sort(ChangeColTypes, {
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 1",
            Order.Ascending
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 2",
            Order.Ascending
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 3",
            Order.Ascending
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 4",
            Order.Ascending
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 5",
            Order.Ascending
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 6",
            Order.Ascending
        },
        {
            Prefix & " Sorting 7",
            Order.Ascending
        }
    }),
    RemoveCols = Table.RemoveColumns(SortCols,{"Path", "HierarchyDepth", "IsLeaf"}),
    ChooseOutput = if CompleteOutput = true then SortCols else RemoveCols
in
    ChooseOutput
,
documentation = [
    Documentation.Name =  " Table.ResolveParentChild",
    Documentation.Description = " Creates columns for all parents, multiple parents are supported",
    Documentation.LongDescription = " Creates columns for all parents, multiple parents are supported",
    Documentation.Category = "Table",
    Documentation.Source = "local",
    Documentation.Author = "Imke Feldmann: www.TheBIccountant.com | Adapted by Ricardo Diaz www.ricardodiaz.co",
    Documentation.Examples = {[Description =  "See: http://wp.me/p6lgsG-sl for more details",
        Code = "",
        Result = ""
        ]}
    ] 
 in 
    Value.ReplaceType(func, Value.ReplaceMetadata(Value.Type(func), documentation))
```